# What is the meaning of: function(x) Ad(get(x))?

Tags: r

I want to get a dataFrame of all the tickers from the Dow Jones 30. I succeed by this method, which gives me all the adjusted.close from the stock. My questions are referring to this line:

```
adj_30 = do.call(merge, lapply(tickers, function(x) Ad(get(x))))
```

1) When referring to "x" in a function, does it refer to the previous function call?

2) In the part "lapply(tickers, function(x) Ad(get(x)) ", what is the documentation on having "Ad" before "(get(x))" to get all adjusted.close only?

3) How can "function(x) Ad(get(x))" only be one argument since it has a space?

```
library(XML)

urldj = "http://money.cnn.com/data/dow30/" 
dj_html = htmlTreeParse(urldj, useInternal = TRUE)
djtable = readHTMLTable(dj_html,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,which=2)
djtable = data.frame(djtable)["Company"]
djtable$Ticker = gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", djtable$Company)
tickers = djtable$Ticker

getSymbols(tickers, from="2013-12-31", to="2016-12-31")
adj_30 = do.call(merge, lapply(tickers, function(x) Ad(get(x))))
```

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-definitions - "The body is a parsed R statement. It is *usually* a collection of statements in braces but *[a function body] can be a single statement, a symbol or even a constant*." In the code `function (x) ..` creates an "anonymous function" which accepts a single argument that is bound to the parameter `x` and subsequently used inside the function.. I'd recommend going through the [standard introduction related manuals](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html).